# How to render entity referenced nodes field inside node.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming, entities, nodes

I have 2 content types: book and author.

### This is the structure:

[image]

I want to use (print) **some** fields of author content type inside the `node-book-tpl.php`.

How can I do that? Is there a method to print referenced entity's fields like `<?php print render($content['field_author']); ?>` etc.?

*Note: I tried the [Inline Entity Display](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_display) module but because I want to do this with custom node-book.tpl.php it doesn't work for me.*

Comment: Use the stored `uid` within the reference field to load the corresponding entity and render whichever field you want. For the image field use [theme_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7.x)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please give more details about `uid`?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no compelling reason to render the fields from within the template, you could simply:

1. choose a certain view mode for your author content type, say: Token, and make it show only those fields you want to be visible in the book node;
2. set the display of the field referencing the author node from the book node to "Rendered entity" / "Rendered as Token".

Answer (score 0):

As you say author is also a content type. Then you get author content node id  on book content.if get node id then use node_load($author_nid); to load author node.print_r() load node and print fields you want to show.